# Rule of thumb as to when the adverb "where" can be omitted

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> A place **where** people go to for entertainment.

the adverb *where* can be omitted so as to obtain:

> A place  people go to for entertainment.

Are there any instances where such deletions are not permissible?
It would be really helpful if one could provide some general guidelines regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a learner:

In your sentence, I believe, since *place* has almost the same meaning as the conjunction *where*, we can remove it. I have seen this happening when the noun has almost the same meaning as the conjunctions. For example:

> *The restaurant we went last time.*
>
> *The store I used to go for buying groceries.*
>
> "Is this the place we used to love?"

However, regarding when we cannot omit the conjunction where, I would say in sentences like

> *Where he hid the documents is not clear yet.*

Here, the conjunction *where* is used to form a noun clause, i.e., where he hid the documents. In this case, removing the conjunction makes the sentence look broken. So, we cannot remove it. Note since I am not a native speaker of English, I won't claim that that's the case for all the noun-clause sentences made up of "where".

Comment: I was actually more interested in examples akin to the first ones you've given (i.e., where **where** acts as a conjunction), I've came up with another example in which , I believe, the meaning of the sentence would be broken if **where** were to be removed, consider: 
     A place **where** a farmer used to live.
(*) A place a farmer used to live.